# How can i prevent emails to be sent on weekends and instead queue it to be sent on Monday from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio

So we want to prevent the sent of the emails that we have in journeys in Marketing cloud to come out on the week-end ( Saturday and Sunday) but queue it to come up on Monday ? Is there an Exclusion script to prevent that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for something like that, but i have not used exclusion-scripts in productive environment until now, so it would be good if someone else confirms this approach.

```
Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()),"ddd") == "Sat" OR Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()),"ddd") == "Sun"
```

The journey would need to be "recurring on each day" (atleast) and you must be exteremely aware of the contact entry mode (no reentry, re entry anytime and reentry only after exiting).

@AmpScript Pros: Is there a function to get DayOfWeek as number and compare like > 5 instead of string comparison? [Have not found something like that, that could be used in exclusion scripts].

> Another approach would be to schedule your journey just on weekdays
>   with recurring. With this approach you do not even need to build an
>   exclusion script. "Recurring Schedule -> Weekdays".

Comment: Thank you Johannes. My entry source is salesforce data so i cannot schedule the journey. If i choose the first solution, is the email queued to be sent on Monday? or it won't be sent at all ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help because I do not know how Salesforce data behaves as entry source